# Eclipse doesn't recognize my colors.xml as an android file

Tags: android, eclipse, colors, highlight, android-xml

My created the `/res/values/colors.xml` and type some content. But eclipse doesn't treat it as an android file, just normal .xml. When I edit my `/res/valuse/strings.xml`, it shows a `"Resources"` view at left down corner. But it's `"Design"` when I edit colors.xml. And eclipse highlights my elements with a ugly color when my cursor on them.

What's the way to make it as Android xml file in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file probably wasn't created properly. Try what @steve said first; however if that doesn't do it (and for future reference) create the file by choosing 'Android xml file' when you hit the 'new file' option in eclipse. It may be listed under 'other'. This will not only set up the file in the correct format, but it has a menu that allows you to specify what type of xml this will be (ie, absolute layout, resource etc...) and can generate some of the boilerplate xml for you based on your choices.

Comment: Oh, How careless I am! Thanks you so much. BTW, if I would like to edit a normal .xml, how can I get rid of the ugly highlight? I see preference->XML->editor but can't catch it...

Comment: Unfortunately I have never seen/cannot replicate the highlight of which you speak. I wish I could be of more help in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

yes i m developing on eclipse only,it will work with condition
-the file should be in value folder
-the tag in which color value is given should be in resources tag

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

#00ff00

or any other color of your choice with color RGB value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you encapsulated the color names with the resources tag?, ie:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#0000ff</color>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Yes, I have. My android application even can be executed by emulator.

Comment: ah, ok - sounds like its an Eclipse-related problem then - I'm not a big Eclipse fan but I use it because it seems to be the easiest way to do Android development.  Have you tried Providences idea above?  Force Eclipse to create the file from new?